# Angular2 change card background for active card/div

Tags: angular

I have a list which I show as cards:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col">
        <div class="goal-list-card" *ngFor="let goal of core_goals| values; let j = index;">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h6 class="">{{goal.title}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action-button">
                <button (click)="editGoal(goal)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on `Edit` Button will open a div that shows details of the selected element.

CSS for these cards:

```
.goal-list-card {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;

}

.goal-list-card .card-title{
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.goal-list-card .card-action-button{
  padding: 2px;
}
```

I want to change the color of the card for which user is currently viewing the details. If he clicks `Edit` of another card then, color of that card will be changed.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to mark card of the goal that is currently edited.
You can save goal.id (assuming you have id in that object) into some variable.
Thank use it to set class on card div:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col">
        <div class="goal-list-card" *ngFor="let goal of core_goals| values; let j = index;" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedGoal == goal.id}">
            <div class="card-title">
                <h6 class="">{{goal.title}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action-button">
                <button (click)="editGoal(goal)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
editGoal(goal) {
    // Some code for your logic
    this.selectedGoal = goal.id;
}
```

Comment: Need to change CSS as well?

Comment: Yes I got it! Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped.